# Multilevel sorting of list of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort the below list:

```
list1 = [('a', 1, 3), ('b', 1, 2), ('c', 2, 1)]
```

based on 2nd(asc) & 3rd element(asc) of each tuple resulting in:

```
[('b', 1, 2), ('a', 1, 3), ('c', 2, 1)]
```

I tried using:

```
sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[1], x[2])
```

but lead to an error:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: You need `lambda x:(x[1],x[2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how:

```
list1 = [('a', 1, 3), ('b', 1, 2), ('c', 2, 1)]

print(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2])))
```

Output:

```
[('b', 1, 2), ('a', 1, 3), ('c', 2, 1)]
```

The reason you get the error is because of the comma in. You see, instead of taking it as part of the `lambda` function, python is interpreting it as you are trying to pass another argument, a positional argument in fact, into the `sorted` function.

Whenever calling a function, passing in keyword arguments before the positional arguments will result in the error you specified.

```
sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[1], x[2])
```

---

Note: the slice `[1:]` works too:

```
list1 = [('a', 1, 3), ('b', 1, 2), ('c', 2, 1)]

print(sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma in your key lambda looks like the end of the argument to the parser. Parenthesize it to disambiguate: `key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2])`.

Alternatively, slicing does the same thing in this case: `key=lambda x: x[-2:]`.

Furthermore, while it doesn't matter on a list this short the `operator.itemgetter` function marginally outperforms a lambda - last time I checked it was about a 10% speedup on larger lists. `key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks like the interpreter is interpreting `key=(lambda x:x[1])` and `(x[2])` as the second and third arguments to `sorted()` respectively. If you put the whole lambda expression in parentheses, then it should work.